# Statement-Level Read Consistency in various SQL/NoSQL DBs

Tags: sql-server, database, mongodb, isolation-level, consistency

Recently I was thinking about query consistency in various SQL and NoSQL databases. What happens, when I have a (long running) query and rows are inserted or updated while the query is running? A simple theoretic example:

Let’s assume the following query takes a long time:

```
SELECT SUM(salary) FROM emp;
```

And while this query is running, another transaction does:

```
UPDATE emp SET salary = salary * 1.05 WHERE salary > 10000;
COMMIT;
```

When the SUM query has read half of the updated employees before the update, and the other half after the update, I would get an inconsistent nonsense result. Does this phenomenon have a name? By definition, it is not really a phantom read, because just one query is involved.

How do various DBs handle this situation? I am especially interested in SQL Server, MongoDB, RavenDB and Azure Table Storage.

Oracle for example guarantees *statement-level read consistency*, which says that the data returned by a single query is committed and consistent for a single point in time.

UPDATE: SQL Server seems to only prevent this kind of problem when READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT is set to ON.

Comment: One can also achieve statement-level read consistency with the `SNAPSHOT` isolation level in SQL Server. Without an explict transaction in the `SNAPSHOT` level, each statement is an independent autocommit transaction that uses row-versioning to provide the read consistent view of committed data at the time the transaction began, similar the behavior of the `READ_COMMITTED` level with the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database option turned on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the term you're looking for is "Dirty Read"

I can answer this one for SQL server.
You get 5 options for transaction isolation level, where the default is READ COMMITTED.

Only READ UNCOMMITTED allows dirty reads. You'll have to specifically enable that using SET TRANSACTION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED.

READ UNCOMMITTED is equivalent to NOLOCK, but syntactically nicer (opinion) as it doesn't need to be repeated for each table in your query.

Possible isolation levels are as below. I've linked the docs for more detail, if future readers find the link stale please edit.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql

READ UNCOMMITTED

READ COMMITTED

REPEATABLE READ

SNAPSHOT

SERIALIZABLE

Answer (score 0):

By default (read committed), you get your query and the update is blocked by the shared lock taken by your SELECT, until it completes.

If you enable Read Committed Snapshot Isolation Level (RCSI) as a database option, you continue to see the previous version of the data but the update isn't blocked.

Similarly, if the update was running first, when you have RSCI enabled, it doesn't block you, but you see the data before the update started.

RCSI is generally (but not 100% always) a good thing. I always design with it on. In Azure SQL DB, it's on by default.